# Change filename by 1 every time (bash script)

Tags: bash, scripting, filenames, increment

I'm making a (bash) script for mass keyfile generation.
I need the script to name the first generated keyfile "1", the next "2" and so on - So I need every filename to be the previous filename + 1.
The script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Files in directory
 dir=$(ls -U -l /home/user/keyfiles|wc -l)
 name=
#script
 target=/home/user/keyfiles/$name
 dd if=/dev/random of=$target bs=1024 count=5
```

As you see, I would like to add 1 to $dir and store it in $name, every time the script is run.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these will work:

```
name=$((dir + 1))
let name=dir+1
```

Comment: or `let dir++` (or any of the others) and just use $dir.

Comment: or even `name=$(($(ls -U -l /home/user/keyfiles|wc -l)+1)`

Answer (score 0):

with bash,

`((dir++))`